# Android : Get status of Asynctask and wait

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using Asynctask to load all the contacts from the device. Although it has been discussed many times that Contacts.Contract is really slow and take me 10-15 secs to load all contacts data with image and all other data like email etc. So I have decided to start a service with asynctask on the splash screen.
Now the problem is 
I have activity series A-B-C-D
Asynctask starts in Activity A and I want Contacts in Activity D. If all contacts is loaded till user reaches Activity D then its ok. But if user reaches Activity D and service is still running than I need to make user wait.

> So my question is HOW TO WAIT FOR ASYNCTASK TO FINISH in Activity D. I will show a simple progress bar in activity D till Asynctask finishes. BUT HOW?

Comment: What about onpostexecute method? Use that. That method is designed for you.

Comment: Mahn my asyntask is in service of android and using onPost in that case is impossible because User may or May not reach Activity D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea to make async series **in just one async task**:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(params[0] == "taskA") {
              //do somthing
              params[0] = "taskB";
            }
            if(params[0] == "taskB") {
              //do somthing
              params[0] = "taskC";
            }
            if(params[0] == "taskC") {
              //do somthing
              params[0] = "taskD";
            }
            if(params[0] == "taskD") {
              //do somthing
              return true;
            }
```

And in your main thread just call async task like this:

```
ShowMyProgress();
new MyAsyncTask().execute("taskA");
```

And finally you can hide your progress on onPostExecute like:

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            ....

            HideMyProgress();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To wait for AsyncTask to finish you can use get() method.
From documentation of get() method:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

[AsyncTask - get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)

But this will make your main thread wait for the result of the AsyncTask.

Another way would be that you can show a progress dialog in the async task until it finishes. This way you can get the status calling:

```
task.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING
```

And if the status is `Status.RUNNING` you will just show the progress dialog until will be finished. So, as an example:

```
    final AsyncTask task = MyAsyncTask.getInstance();

    final Thread waitingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // ...
                // show progress dialog
                while(task.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED) {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
                result = task.get();
                // ...
                // hide progress dialog
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO log
            }
        }
    });

    waitingThread.start();
```

The `task` object is your asyncTask. You can make it Singleton and start in Activity A, and get instance of it in Activity D.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private static MyAsyncTask instance;

        private MyAsyncTask(){}

        public static MyAsyncTask getInstance() {
            // check status if we want to execute it again
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MyAsyncTask();
            } else if (instance.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) {
                instance = new MyAsyncTask();
            }

            return instance;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do smth
            return null;
        }
}
```

Haven't tried this in action but I think it will work.

Comment: `get()` blocks the ui thread waiting fro the result. This makes Asynctask no more Asynchronous. So this suggestion is wrong

Comment: You should not block the ui thread. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html and this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: I have suggested another way to do it. Please check my answer.

Comment: The "task" object is your asyncTask. You can make it Singleton and start in Activity A, and get instance of it in Activity D.

Comment: What if my asynctask is an Inner type of my Service class?

Comment: It depends on how it is implemented. If everything is done in AsyncTask then it doesn't matter. You can post the code of your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
myAsyn asyn = new myAsyn();
asyn.execute();

while(asyn.getStatus()!=Aynctask.Status.Finished)
{
Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

**instead of waiting for asyntask to finish, you can simply show a progress dialog.**

```
public class myAsyn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do your work
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
     }
```

Comment: I know how to use it but what if I started it from service and wanna wait for it in my Activity D? I want to Fulfill a Listview in Activity D

Answer (score 0):

It is simple i will explain..

You can get the status of the async task task...like this

```
if (o2.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) { ////o2 is a asynch task instance...

} else if (o2.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {

} else if (o2.getStatus() == Status.PENDING) {

}
```

Comment: My asynctask is started from service and has its object in service what should I do if I want it in my Activity which had NOT STARTED IT

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //declare other objects as per your need
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);

        //do initialization of required objects objects here                
    };      
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {   

         //do loading operation here  
        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


  progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
 }
```

You can call this using

```
LoadData task = new LoadData();
task.execute();
```

To check whether your Service is still running::

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I know ho to use asynctask mahn but the thing is starting and handling it in one activity taking a lot of time. So I am starting it on my activity A so that user do not wait for 10 sec on a single screen and the time will be splitted

Comment: Cause its taking too much time

Comment: yeah I can do that but I have to wait for asynctask to complete and for how long do I check this method?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has basically `onPreExecute` and `doInbackground`, and `onPostExecute` exists. The meaning of each!

`onPreExecute`: 
Runs on the UI thread before `doInBackground (Params. ..)`.

`opPostExecute`: 
Runs on the UI thread after `doInBackground (Params. ..)`. The specified result is the value returned by `doInBackground (Params. ..)`.

This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.

The order in which the calls

One. `onPreExecute`

Two. `doInbackground`

Three. `onPostExecute`

However `doInbackground` operate in the other thread.

Must be treated so well `doInbackground` result is passed three times because of `onPreExecute()` to create a progress bar progress bar to end its `onPostExecute` could work.

Comment: I know how to use it but what if I started it from service and wanna wait for it in my Activity D?